# Migrate data from MySQL to Flowable

Tags: mysql, ssis, data-migration, flowable

Current version of our application holds data in MySQL. We have a new version, which is developed in Flowable.

- What is the best way to migrate data from MySQL to Flowable?
- Is    there any APIs available to do this task?
- If not, is there any
  documentation about how to design an ETL process to load data to
  Flowable?

I can see Flowable Database schema in their documentations but I couldn't find any clue about migrating data from an external system to Flowable. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Flowable is not a database therefore migrating data from MySQL to Flowable is not something that can be done.

Flowable supports storing its data in different Databases.

What you are most likely looking for is migrating your business logic to Flowable. There are ways to do this using the Flowable Java APIs in order to bring your old business data in the new state you will need using Flowable.

There is no specific documentation for this because this highly depends on your own business needs.

Comment: Do we need to create Java APIs from scratch to do this work or is there any pre built component available already?

Comment: Flowable has Java APIs that allow you to create Process Instances, move process instances to a certain state and etc

Comment: I am totally new to Flowable. It would be great if you could share some articles about this sort of data migration work?

Comment: We have migrated the business logic to flowable. Now we need to bring data from the legacy system to the corresponding process/table/screen in the new system designed in Flowable. How can we do that? Any sample documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no one size fits all, as this is extremely dependent on individual processes.